# outer loop not looping in Python

Tags: python, loops, nested

I am very new to programming so apologies if this is a simple question. I have looked online but haven't found the answer to my problem.

I'm using a nested loop in Python to add values to an array. In summary my code is below (I have translated it to make it general for here so hopefully this is done correctly). It works fine through the first iteration of the "j" loop, but instead of looping through the remaining "j" values in the outer loop, it just returns the array for j=0 completed.

Why is my loop breaking? Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: After running a few more tests it seems the "elif" statement is stopping the outer loop. I'm still confused as to why this is.

UPDATE2: I have added the actual code I am using below. The issue seems to occurs in the "else" loop.

```
def create_pixel_peaklist(rawfilename, threshold, ppm_tolerance):
    peaklist = create_avg_peaklist(rawfile, 0.5)
    spectra_list = raw_to_list(rawfile)
    intensity_array = np.zeros((len(spectra_list), len(peaklist[0])))
    for j in range(0, len(peaklist[0])):
        mz = peaklist[0][j]
        ppm_tolerance = (ppm_tolerance/1e6)*mz
        for i in range (0, len(spectra_list)):
            idx_range = (np.where((spectra_list[i][0] > (mz-ppm_tolerance)) & (spectra_list[i][0] < (mz+ppm_tolerance))))
            if len(idx_range[0]) == 0:
                peak_intensity = 0
            else:
                len(idx_range[0]) == 1
                idx = idx_range[0][0]
                #end_idx = idx_range[0][-1]
                peak_intensity = spectra_list[i][1][idx]
                intensity_array[i][j] = peak_intensity
                print ('processed peak idx ' + str(j) + ' in scan ' + str(i) + ' for mz ' + str(mz))
    return intensity_array
```

Comment: This could be a problem of indentation, but it is impossible to say, because the code you pasted has completely wrong indentation. It's currently a syntax error. Please fix it so that it is exactly as you have it.

Comment: I have copied the actual code I am using to avoid these errors

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is inside of the outer loop, that is why the function returns the value, move it ouside of the outer loop instead:

```
create_array = np.zeros((len(list1), len(list2)))
for j in range(0, len(list2)):
   parameter  = list2[j]
   ppm_tolerance = parameter/1e6
    for i in range (0, len(list1)):
        idx = (np.where((list1[i] > (parameter-ppm_tolerance)) & (list2[i] < (parameter+ppm_tolerance))))
        if len(idx_range[0]) == 0:
            intensity = 0
        elif len(idx_range[0]) == 1:
            idx = idx
            #end_idx = idx_range[0][-1]
            intensity = list1[i][idx]
            create_array[i][j] = intensity
return create_array # <----- Moved outside of the j-loop
```

This way the entire nested loop will be performed BEFORE the array is returned.

Comment: Thanks. Actually that was an error when I copied into here. As you show it is is how I already have it. But still outer loop wont run

Comment: @NoIdea Then please can you edit the question to show the code how you have it.

Comment: even if i remove the return statement and print the current "i" and "j" values, it still stops at j=0

Answer (score 0):

In that 'i' loop, idx will be True or False if I am not wrong. Do you get any error-messages from your interpreter, than please can you add it to your question?
I think your idx_range causing some trouble.

Comment: no error, it just returns  the array with only the j=0 row filled

Comment: where did you define the variable idx_range ?

Comment: A few things went wrong when I tried to generalize the code. I have now updated my question with the actual code I am using that should fix these issues.